# Is it possible to signup to programmatically create analytics account?

Tags: google-analytics-firebase

I would like to programmatically create a gmail, and google analytics account as well as tracking code.

Are there any APIs to do this?

Will I have to essentially have to simulate a browser in order to do the signup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the v3 version of analytics, there was a provisioning API that was invitation only. I never got the invitation. So don't know how it works. But here is the link
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/provisioning/v3/